# Get RSS with simplexml and insert in DB gives me strange characters for &#8217;

Tags: php, mysql

For example the following feed: http://blog.optimizely.com/feed/ has a title emement like so:

```
<title>
Lessons in Marketing from Daft Punk (Hint: It&#8217;s 
  Not Just About Getting Lucky)
</title>
```

This title ends up in my database like so:

> Lessons in Marketing from Daft Punk (Hint: Itâ€™s Not Just About
>   Getting Lucky)

The tables are set to use UTF-8

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file($item['Rss']);
$items=$this->getItems($rss);
foreach($items as $article){
    if($this->shouldInsert($article)){
        $this->insertItem($article,$item["id"]);
    }else{
        var_dump("skipping:");
        continue 2;
    }
}
    //the getItems function:
public function getItems($xml){
    if(count($xml->channel)!==0){
        return $xml->channel->item;
    }
    if(count($xml->feed)!==0){
        return $xml->feed->entry;
    }
    if(count($xml->entry)!==0){
        return $xml->entry;
    }
    return [];
}
    //insertItem:
public function insertItem($item,$sourceID){
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'usr', 'pwd');
    $title=(string) $item->title;
    $url=$this->getLink($item);
    $pubDate=$this->getPubDate($item);//pubdate is optional
    if($pubDate!==false){
        $pubDate=new DateTime($pubDate);
        $pubDate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s e',$pubDate->getTimestamp());
    }
    $now=new DateTime();
    $inserted=date('Y-m-d H:i:s e',$now->getTimestamp());
    $query="insert into tblItems (title,url,clicks,pubdate,inserted,sourceid)" .
     "values ("
     .$dbh->quote($title)
     .",".$dbh->quote($url)
     .",0"
     .",".$dbh->quote($pubDate)
     .",".$dbh->quote($inserted)
     .",".$sourceID.")";
    $stm=$dbh->query($query);
    $dbh=null;
}
```

Comment: You're probably storing the UTF-8 character in a latin1 field. Also, `™` is not in the initial string you've posted above.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté The string as posted is as shown on the page and as shown to me in phpmyadmin. Forgot to mention the tables are utf-8 (updated question) and looks like this particular feed is utf-8.

Comment: Ah, I see. The title didn't show the string correctly. will update the question. The question body shows it correctly.

Comment: So I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'usr', 'pwd');
```

to

```
$dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf-8", 'usr', 'pwd',
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

Comment: +1 It displays the strings correctly now the correct connection is new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8" (no minus sign). Thank you for this.